# CreateDatabaseScript attempts to update database according to migration in C# MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
public static void ProvisionTenant(string tenantSchema, DbConnection connection)
    {
        using (var ctx = Create(tenantSchema, connection))
        {
            if (!ctx.Database.Exists())
            {
                ctx.Database.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                var createScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
                ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(createScript);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Above code is where I get stuck.
var createScript is the line.

I am attempting to get multi-tenancy working (with multiple schemas) in C# MVC.
This is the code that provisions a tenant into the database.

I have 2 tenants that attempt to be created in my initialization file/code.

The code in that makes some DDL scripts that add the new schema and tables into the schema etc.

So when the script is being made, ONCE, and ONLY ONCE, it was successfully made for one of the tenants, then in the next tenant it error'd.

I had a look at the script before it was executed (that one successful time), and it had the right DDL! So that's a good start.

The rest of the times when it won't work is when it randomly goes to my only migration's (named: update1) designer.cs file, and constantly loops through parts of it, then attempts to update my database using THAT migration!
When it does that, obviously the database will attempt to add tables, one of them being the __MigrationHistory table, so it throws a fit saying, that table is already there.

Why is my script NOT making a script but attempting to update the database according to the latest migration?!

Here's the code for the designer.cs file for 'update1' migration (my one and only migration):

```
// <auto-generated />
namespace CRMMVC.Migrations
{
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure;
    using System.Resources;

    [GeneratedCode("EntityFramework.Migrations", "6.1.3-40302")]
    public sealed partial class update1 : IMigrationMetadata
    {
        private readonly ResourceManager Resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(update1));

        string IMigrationMetadata.Id
        {
            get { return "201510271010339_update1"; }
        }

        string IMigrationMetadata.Source
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        string IMigrationMetadata.Target
        {
            get { return Resources.GetString("Target"); }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
So I made another migration called update2Empty, and ran update-database. So obviously that one is empty.

The CreateDatabaseScript() method this time went to Configuration.cs to check that AutomaticMigrationsEnabled is true, then, went to the private readonly ResourceManager Resources = new... Line in update1's designer.cs file, then started looping through update2Empty and update1's designer.cs file's string ImigrationMetadata.Id, constantly getting each one of their's, then switching to the other.

Then finally going back to update1's designer.cs, grabbing the IMigrationMetaData.Source then going through ImigrationMetaData.Target, and finally, attempting to run all of update1!

This is insane, any ideas? I hope that description helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private CRMContext(DbConnection connection, DbCompiledModel model)
    : base(connection, model, contextOwnsConnection: false)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<CRMContext>(null);
}
```

Just added that line (one and only line) to the constructor used by the tenant code.

I needed to tell the database to not use the intializer everytime I used the constructor with a connection string. Why? I don't know, but it stopped the multiple loops going through.

That's it. Literally it.